# Failed to load 'libmain.so' java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libmain.so" not found

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, unity-game-engine

I export my unity project as android and made the export as a aar library using android studio. And imported this library to my another android project, but when i try to start the UnityPlayerActivity i am getting this issue ->

Failed to load 'libmain.so'        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libmain.so" not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that i have to include this in my app build.gradle

```
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
```

[image]